# How to set permissions so that files cannot be deleted?

Tags: permissions

Is there a way to setup a directory such that files and directories

- can be read
- written to
- created

but NOT deleted. This is for my photo archive. I want to avoid accidentally deleting photos. Is there a way to do this?

PS/ I have set the archive up using bindfs if that is any help. Two users and one group have 0750 access.

Comment: If you allow writing, you allow overwriting which is essentially the same as deleting.

Comment: @terdon, I know, that why I am asking the question... there surely must be a way, right?

Comment: I don't see how if you need to allow writing. If I can write to `file`, I can run `> file` and that effectively deletes your data. Muru gave you what is probably the best solution you'll get at the directory level. I suggest you use that and then also set all files to read-only.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the append-only attribute. From [`man chattr`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/chattr.1.html):

```
A  file  with the `a' attribute set can only be open in append mode for
writing.   Only   the   superuser   or   a   process   possessing   the
CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.
```

For directories, this means that new entries can be created, but no entry can be renamed or deleted:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ sudo chattr +a foo
$ touch foo/bar
$ echo a > foo/bar
$ rm foo/bar
rm: cannot remove 'foo/bar': Operation not permitted
$ mv foo/bar foo/baz
mv: cannot move 'foo/bar' to 'foo/baz': Operation not permitted
```

This attribute does not inherit, so you will have to apply this to all subdirectories recursively:

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chattr +a {} +
```

Comment: Nice, +1. This still doesn't protect the OP's data though. You can still run `> foo/bar` and effectively delete the file's data.

Comment: terdon, that might be the case, but my photos will only be accessed via Nautilus, so that should not be a problem, right?

Comment: @terdon and you can set immutable or append-only on all the files as well, though photo editing will be a pain

Comment: Do you also have to apply it to existing files?

Comment: @don.joey depends - do you want to make them all append-only? You haven't really said what you want to happen when writing  to the files.